# SSRS prompt to work with mysql database using unxtimestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Has anyone come across a solution to get the prompt working on SSRS which uses MySQL where the prompt I need is a unix timpstamp. The SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Concat(o.order_no, '-', o.order_no_iteration) 
            AS `order_no` 
            , 
            o.customer_order_no, 
            IF(o.on_hold = '1', 'Hold', CASE o.status 
                                          WHEN 'D' THEN 'Draft' 
                                          WHEN 'P' THEN 'Pending' 
                                          WHEN 'R' THEN 'Rejected' 
                                          WHEN 'A' THEN 'Approved' 
                                          WHEN 'E' THEN 'Pending [EDI]' 
            WHEN 'W' THEN 'Pending iWorld Approval' 
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'Pending Interface Approval' 
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cancelled' 
                                        end) 
            AS `order_status`, 
            IF(j.status IS NULL 
                OR j.status = '' 
                OR o.status = 'P', 'No worksheet', CASE j.status 
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'Incomplete' 
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Complete' 
                                                   end) 
            AS `jobsheet_status`, 
            p.property_name_number, 
            p.property_address1, 
            p.property_town, 
            p.property_postcode, 
            og.organisation_name, 
            b.name, 
            Concat('PO-', po.purchase_order_no) 
            AS `purchase_order_no`, 
            s.suppliers_name, 
            po.delivery_status, 
            po.supplier_invoice_ref, 
            IF(o.provisional_date != '', Date_format( 
                                         From_unixtime(o.provisional_date), 
                                         '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), '') 
            AS `provisional_date`, 
            IF(po.dateadded != '', Date_format(From_unixtime(po.dateadded), 
                                   '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i' 
                                   ), '') 
            AS `date_added`, 
            IF(o.estimated_completion_date != '', 
            Date_format( 
            From_unixtime(o.estimated_completion_date), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 
            '') AS 
            `estimated_completion_date`, 
            IF(j.actual_completion_date_set != '', 
            Date_format(j.actual_completion_date_set, 
            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), '')      AS 
            `system_completion_date`, 
            o.total_value_budget, 
            Sum(pod.total), 
            o.total_value_budget - Sum(pod.total) 
            AS `margin` 
FROM   purchase_orders po 
   LEFT JOIN purchase_order_main_details pod 
          ON pod.purchase_order_id = po.purchase_order_id 
   LEFT JOIN main_detail md 
          ON pod.main_detail_id = md.main_detail_id 
   LEFT JOIN orders o 
          ON md.order_id = o.order_id 
   LEFT JOIN jobsheet j 
          ON j.group_id = o.order_id 
   LEFT JOIN properties p 
          ON p.property_id = md.property_id 
   INNER JOIN organisation og 
           ON o.client_id = og.organisation_id 
   INNER JOIN organisation_business_unit obu 
           ON obu.organisation_id = og.organisation_id 
   LEFT JOIN business_units b 
          ON b.business_unit_id = obu.business_unit_id 
   LEFT JOIN suppliers s 
          ON s.supplier_id = po.supplier_id 
WHERE  From_unixtime(po.dateadded, "%d/%m/%y") BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2 
   AND po.pad_no <> 'Automatic' 
GROUP  BY o.order_id, 
      customer_order_no, 
      purchase_order_no 
ORDER  BY purchase_order_no
```

I have tried formatting the parameter in SSRS in the expression as

```
=format(Parameters!d1.Value,"dd/mm/yy")
```

I have also modified the sql to use:

```
where str_to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(po.dateadded, "%d/%m/%Y"),'%d/%m/%Y') 
between str_to_date(@d1,'%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date(@d2,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

and hasn't worked, tried every different combination, but just feel hopeless

Comment: Are you taking the date parameter as Date/Time type or is it just a String?

Comment: Yes on SSRS, I am setting it as a date/time so the calander can pop in parameter for users to chose a date from the calendar. The actual field itself is a unix timestamp which is a character field which I have converted to date on both the sql and ssrs, but without any joy!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your where clause with

`WHERE po.dateadded between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(@d1, "%d/%m/%y")) 
 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(@d2, "%d/%m/%y"))`